# Convertto-JSON forcing empty or null valued arrays into arrays with an index of 1?

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I'm using `ConvertTo-JSON` to create a nested JSON doc with various nested arrays. That all works, but in the case that I have an empty or null valued array, `ConvertTo-JSON` is forcing the resulting JSON to contain `[""]` instead of `[ ]`. I've tried if statements to ensure the array has an index of zero before putting it through the cmdlet. what I want is `[ ]`

Is there a way to force this?

```
            $version = $null
            $profile = $null
            $versions = $null
            $versionsAsArray = $null
            $offices = $null
            $roles = $null
            $versions = [ordered]@{
                    "version" = $active_version;
                    "default_office" = $line.'Default Office'.TrimEnd("`n");
                    "offices" = [array]$offices;
                    "roles" = [array]$roles;
            }
            [array]$versionsAsArray += $versions
            [array]$docArray += $versionsAsArray
            $docArray | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4 | Out-File -FilePath $env:USERPROFILE\desktop\abc.json -Force
```

This is what I get in the JSON

```
                             "offices":  [
                                             ""
                                         ],
                             "roles":  [
                                           ""
                                       ]
```

Comment: Please show us the exact code you're executing (or [a representative sample that exhibits the described behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) :)

Comment: If you want to ensure `[ ]` then you need to wrap an expression in `@( )` in powershell

Comment: I did that too. it didn't work. for example `if( $offices.count -eq 1 -and $offices -like "")
            {
                [array]$offices = @ ( ) }`

Comment: you just need to do `"offices" = @($offices)` and so on, also you have a space between `@` and `(` so thats wrong

Comment: tried it. still giving me `"offices":  [""]`

Comment: sounds like your variables either have an empty string, or have been constrained to be `[string]` / `[string[]]`. you can compare `ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @([string]::Empty)` vs `ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @()` to see what I mean

Comment: ```$offices``` is *probably* a string value containing the empty string before you cast it to an array - for example the output from ```[string] $offices = $null; ConvertTo-Json -InputObject ([array] $offices)``` gives```[ "" ]``` because ```[string] $offices = $null`` assigned the **empty string** to ```$offices``` due to the ```[string]``` cast. Re-casting **that** to an array gives the equivalent of ```@( "" )```...

Comment: what about something like this? `($docArray | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4) -replace '""', "" | Out-File -FilePath $env:USERPROFILE\desktop\abc.json -Force`